# Dividing a graph into $k$ subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an algorithm for finding the number of ways a given connected graph can be divided into $k$ connected subgraphs? I've searched the Web for an answer, but perhaps I'm using the wrong words as my graph theory is rusty. Basically, given a set of vertices, I'm looking for the number of ways this set can be split into $k$ disjoint subsets, where each subset of vertices is connected. 
[image]

With the graph example above and $k=3$, a possible division would be {A, B, D}, {C, F, H} and {E, G}. An example of a disallowed subset would be {A, F} as they are not directly connected.

**EDIT**

Suppose I narrowed the scope to a grid graph like the one below:

[image]

Would that help find an algorithm?

Comment: Are you interested in an actually feasible algorithm to run it on a computer or for theoretic purpose?

Comment: @M. Winter: I'm looking for an algorithm to run on a computer, but if you have a more theoretic answer, that would also be welcome.

Comment: Without any restrictions I would just suggest the exhaustive search. That of course is no option for a real program.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(k, h, w)$ denote the number of ways to partition an $h\times w$ grid into $k$ connected subgraphs. Since not much has been said in quite some time, I wanted to reignite this with some observations. The answer to the special case of a grid of length $w$ and height 1, i.e., a $w$-vertex path is the number of compositions of $w$ into $k$ parts:

$$
F(k, 1, w) =\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$

We can use this to find a lower bound for heights other than 1, as long as $k\geq h$. We do this by counting only the subgraphs restricted to a path at a given height which we call a *level*. Let $C_h(k)$ denote the set of compositions of $k$ into $h$ parts. For $c\in C_h(k)$ let $c_i$ denote the $i$th term. Fix a composition of $k$ into $h$ parts, say $c=[c_1, \dots, c_h]$. Then

$$
\sum_{i=1}^h F(c_i, 1, w)
$$

is the number of ways to split an $h\times w$ grid into $k$ connected subgraphs, such that each subgraph is contained in a given level, and the number of subgraphs at level $i$ is $c_i$. Hence,

$$
\sum_{c\in C_h(k)}\sum_{i=1}^h F(c_i, 1, w)\leq F(k, h, w),
$$

where equality only holds if $h=1$, since there are always subgraphs crossing levels otherwise.

This is only a trivial lower bound, but I think one could potentially come up with some closed form combinatorial answer for grids (but probably not in general graphs).

An aside: If you are not interested in labeled graphs, then, in fact, the number of possible subgraph partitions is $P(n, k)$: the number of integer partitions of $n$ of size $k$. For instance, $P(4, 2) = |\{2, 2\}, \{1, 3\}|=2$. We have a recursive definition
$$P(n, k) = P(n-k, k)+P(n-1, k-1),$$
which can be used in an algorithm. But this is probably of no use once you allow less trivial grids.